# How to ask new professor about research projects

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am interested in research topics of one professor that just got tenure track. How can I ask him about upcoming projects on that university?

Comment: Why not just write to them and ask? Please clarify if you are looking for an advisor and if so, in what country?

Answer (score 1):

Just ask. Email or go to his office. I do it all the time and they never mind. They usually appreciate the opportunity to talk about their projects.